# MagicalRecord creating won't save new data object.

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have this code:

```
HLMReferenceData *referenceDataObj = [HLMReferenceData createEntity];
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    HLMReferenceData *localReferenceData = [referenceDataObj inContext:localContext];
    // Setup localReferenceData here ....
}
                  completion:NULL];
```

As far as I can see this is exactly in line with the examples on the net of how to create a new record using MagicalRecord. However it does not work. I get this in the log:

```
... +[MagicalRecord(ErrorHandling) defaultErrorHandler:](0x3abdc4) Error Message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133000.)
... +[MagicalRecord(ErrorHandling) defaultErrorHandler:](0x3abdc4) Error Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
... +[MagicalRecord(ErrorHandling) defaultErrorHandler:](0x3abdc4) Recovery Suggestion: (null)
... -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x954b680) NO CHANGES IN ** UNNAMED ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING
```

I've dug around inside Magical Record's codebase and the error occurs when the `inContext:` method is called. It returns a nil object as a result. I've searched the web and have not been able to figure out what is wrong. The `HLMReferenceData` class is mapped to a single table in the data model with no links to other tables. All the fields in the class get populated.

I'm at a loss.

Comment: Are you using MR shorthand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inContext:` is returning nil because your object was created/inserted in the outer context, and never saved. Therefore it is not yet accessible in the `localContext`. (More specifically, inContext: will try look up the object using a temporary objectID, and it won't find one.) You should create/insert the object inside the save block, like this:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    HLMReferenceData *referenceDataObj = [HLMReferenceData createEntityInContext:localContext];
    referenceDataObj.name = @"foo";
    // Continue setting up referenceDataObj here ....
} completion: NULL];
```

You can see a very similar example on Magical Record's github docs, under Saving. See the subsection 'Changes to saving in MagicalRecord 2.3.0'

https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/Docs/Saving.md

Comment: Hmm, this works for some of my very simple cases. But it's not working for others. I need to be able to do `[MyClass createEntity]`, use the object and then save it later in another class. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, or what you mean by 'save it later in another class.' You mean save it in another context? you can defer saving as long as you want, but in the end you will need to save any insertions or changes in the context in which they occurred. unsaved insertions and changes will not be visible across contexts.

Comment: Thats the problem. The developers creating the objects are not aware of the contexts. In the end I just stopped using saveWithBlock and changed to saving at the persistent store level. Solved everything.