# Howto create core data entities outside of MagicalRecord's saveWithBlock

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

This is a follow on from [My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738625/magicalrecord-creating-wont-save-new-data-object)

The essence is that I need to create a core data object in one class and pass it to another class which then saves it. The situation is complicated by the fact we are trying to use MagicalRecord which insists on creating a different context. Here is a cut down block of code that shows the problem (this is in a unit test):

```
__block HLMReferenceData *referenceData = [HLMReferenceData MR_createEntity];
__block NSManagedObjectID *objId = nil;
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    HLMReferenceData *localReferenceData = [referenceData MR_inContext:localContext];
    [localContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[localReferenceData] error:NULL];
    objId = localReferenceData.objectID;
}
                  completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *saveError){
                      referenceData = (HLMReferenceData *)[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] existingObjectWithID:objId error:NULL];
                  }];
```

Essentially we are creating the object, passing it to a MR save call, then re-retrieving the object so we can continue to use it.

This throws a core data 133000 error when it executes the `... MR_inContext:localContext];` method. It appears to stem from the fact that the main context has not saved the record and it still has a temporary id.

Really need some help with this as we need to be able to create objects outside MR's saveWithBlock: code.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have quite the same problem...

Comment: We found a "hack" that we don't like, but works. We basically re-coded to avoid MR using multiple contexts. In other places we manually manage objects outside of MR. In short, MR is not the magic bullet it claims to be.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: You are using MagiaclRecord 2.3beta5.  If not, please post your version.

You actually are creating your object outside of MagicalRecord's `-saveWithBlock:`.  Your first line does that.  It creates an object in the MR_defaultContext, but that object is not persisted.  It only exists in the MR_defaultContext.  If you want to persist that object, then you can simply do:

```
 [referenceData.managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait]; // or a variant of
```

You can pass `referenceData` to another object, viewController, whatever, even if it isn't saved.